# Parse Parameter-Value-string and link value (of type string) to variable (of specific type)

Tags: c++

How would you structure a set of parameter value pairs if the parameter data types are different?

Suppose you have a large set of parameters that are bound in a larger software like this:

```
string name;
int counter;
//...
float temperature;
bool enableState;
```

To set the value of a parameter manually a string should be accepted via commandline (e.g. "Name=Eric","Counter=100","Temperature=20.0",...).

The search is for a suitable structure for the parameters so that they (or at least the information to read/write them) can be stored in an array. Since the values have different data types, they cannot be stored in an array, but is it purposeful with their pointers (?).
How can the (string) values of the input string be assigned to variables that have fix data types?

Whatever I'm trying doesn't lead to anything or it is a tremendous effort, which makes me believe that a possible (and simple) solution might not be trivial.

The code is supposed to run on an arduino.

**Edit:**
I found a way to do it and it seems to work quite well. But I'm not sure, maybe I did fundamental misstakes. Could you confirm that the code in my answer is legal, so I can set the question to 'solved'?

Comment: You could use a `std::map<std::string, std::variant<int, float, bool, std::string>> variantList;`. It does require c++17 however.

Comment: This looks pretty much like what i was asking for, but I should have mentioned that the code is supposed to run on an arduino plattform. I'm not sure if it will work with c++17...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, but I'm not sure if I will get problems with memory allocation. Beside others I also need string parameters linked to global string variables. The parameters need to be global as well. I'm linking the variables to the parameters with thier memory address, but I'm not sure if that's legal...
My solution is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

enum Access {NO_ACCESS,READ,WRITE,READ_WRITE};
enum DataType {INTEGER,FLOAT,STRING,BOOLEAN};

// parameter-class
class Parameter {
  public:
    long int address;
    string (*setEventAddress) ();
    string (*getEventAddress) ();
    string parameterName;
    Access access;
    DataType datatype;

    string set(string value) {
      if(!(access==WRITE || access==READ_WRITE)){
        return "ERROR: no write access";
      }
      string response="";
      switch (datatype){
        case INTEGER:
          response = setInteger(value,address);
          break;
        case FLOAT:
          response = setFloat(value,address);
          break;
        case STRING:
          response = setString(value,address);
          break;
        case BOOLEAN:
          response = setBool(value,address);
          break;
        default:
          response = "ERROR: unknown data type";
          break;
      }
      if(setEventAddress!=NULL){
        string eventResponse=setEventAddress();
      }
      return response;
    }
    string get(){
      if(!(access==READ || access==READ_WRITE)){
        return "ERROR: no read access";
      }
      string response="";
      switch (datatype){
        case INTEGER:
          response = getInteger(address);
          break;
        case FLOAT:
          response = getFloat(address);
          break;
        case STRING:
          response = getString(address);
          break;
        case BOOLEAN:
          response = getBool(address);
          break;
        default:
          response = "ERROR: unknown data type";
          break;
      }
      if(setEventAddress!=NULL){
        string eventResponse=setEventAddress();
      }
      return response;
    }

    string setInteger(string valueRaw, long int address) {
      int value = stoi(valueRaw);
      *(int*)(address)=value;
      return "Done";
    }
    string setFloat(string valueRaw, long int address) {
      float value = stof(valueRaw);
      *(float*)(address)=value;
      return "Done";
    }
    string setString(string valueRaw, long int address) {
      string value = valueRaw;
      *(string*)(address)=value;
      return "Done";
    }
    string setBool(string valueRaw, long int address) {
      bool value = true;
      if (valueRaw.compare("true") == 0) {
        *(bool*)(address)=true;
      } else {
        *(bool*)(address)=false;
      }
      return "Done";
    }

    string getInteger(long int address) {
      int& i = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(address);
      return to_string(i);
    }
    string getFloat(long int address) {
      float& f = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(address);
      return to_string(f);
    }
    string getString(long int address) {
      string& s = *reinterpret_cast<string*>(address);
      return s;
    }
    string getBool(long int address) {
      bool& b = *reinterpret_cast<bool*>(address);
      return to_string(b);
    }

    Parameter(string n, Access a, DataType d, long int varPointer, string (*setFuncPointer)(), string (*getFuncPointer)());
};

// constructor for parameter
Parameter::Parameter(string n, Access a, DataType d, long int varPointer, string (*setFuncPointer)()=NULL, string (*getFuncPointer)()=NULL) {
  parameterName=n;
  access=a;
  datatype=d;
  address=varPointer;
  setEventAddress=setFuncPointer;
  getEventAddress=getFuncPointer;
}

// functions optionally executed when parameter becomes set/get
string exampleSetEvent() {
  // do anything when parameter is set
  return m;
}

string exampleGetEvent() {
  // do anything when parameter is read
  return m;
}


// a parameter constists of the variable and an object of the parameter-class
// and is simply introduced by adding only two lines
string name;
Parameter Name ("Name", READ_WRITE, STRING, (long int) &name);

int counter;
Parameter Counter ("Counter",READ_WRITE, STRING, (long int) &counter, exampleSetEvent, example);


float temperature;
Parameter Temperature ("Temperature", READ_WRITE, STRING, (long int) &temperature);


bool enableState;
Parameter EnableState ("EnableState", READ_WRITE, STRING, (long int) &enableState);
```

Does anyone see any problems?
In my understanding the memory address of a global object necessarily must stay the same during the entire runtime. Is that correct?
How about strings? As the size of strings is not given explicitly, how can the memory for a string be allocated at compile time? Only the start address of a string gets allocated, I guess.

Comment: It looks ok for memory, but those variables passed by reference to the constructor cannot leave the scope, or must be allocated on the heap. If they leave the scope (popped off of the stack) then the memory will no longer belong to those variables and may be overwritten. I would also recommend passing an pointer rather than a long int because it makes it more readable that address is actually the location in memory of the data you are storing.

Comment: You're right, I will use a pointer for address! But about the constructor: the variables passed by reference to the constructor are assigned to the class attributes, which are global. Won't they remain the same even if the reference they were initialized with changes?

Comment: @Pillager225 address points to variables of variable datatypes (depends on the data type of the corresponding parameter). So I can't use a pointer for address, as the data type of the variable I want to point at is not fix. Did you see that or is there a way to do it either?

Comment: My understanding is that the global variable's addresses will remain the same after you initialize them because they will be in the data portion of memory. Before initialization (after declaration) they will be on the bss, so don't get the address of them then because after initialization they move to the data portion.

Comment: I understand how you are using address, but you can use a pointer of any datatype because when you "decode" the variable, you will decode it into whatever pointer you need. The "address" is just a placeholder. I would say use a void * to be explicit, but I have gotten errors related to "invalid use of void expression" so I usually just use an unsigned *. Honestly it is up to you as it is kind of a stylistic choice. If you comment your code well enough it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I noticed that you also asked about the length of strings in your answer. Well std::string has a length method that will tell you the length of the string and for char *s you can call strlen on them to determine their length.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `std::map<std::string, std::function<void(std::string&)>> variableMap` and fill it up with lambdas like this.

```
std::string name;
int counter;
...

variableMap["Name"] = [&](std::string& val) {
    name = val;
}

variableMap["Counter"] = [&](std::string& val) {
    counter = std::stoi(val);
}
```

And then use it something like this

```
//Get the input and parse it, eg "Name=Chris"
std::string variableName; // Holds "Name"
std::string variableValue; // Holds "Chris"

if (variableMap.find(variableName) != variableMap.end())
    variableMap[variableName](variableValue);
```

Comment: I didn't know maps! But I also found a way to do it, could you please inspect my answer? Maybe I can't do it like that...

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to have a struct store the data as a unsigned char * and then have some meta data about how to decode the unsigned char * in the struct. Something like

```
typedef struct FlexibleStruct {
    char * metaData;
    // this data type here doesn't matter because we will cast it to what we want
    unsigned char * data;
} FlexibleStruct;
```

Then when you want to store it:

```
FlexibleStruct f;
f.metaData = "float";
f.data = (unsigned char *)floatToStore; // This should be a pointer to a float on the heap
```

and to retrieve the data:

```
if(strcmp(f.metaData, "float") == 0) {
    float *retrievedFloat = (float *)f.data;
    printf("%f\n", *retrievedFloat);
}
```

This will work with any data type (even structs) in any version of c or c++!

I tested this on gcc 6.4.0, but I don't know if it will work for avr-g++. I can provide more information if you'd like.

Comment: That looks good, but will it also work with strings? will be possible with your approach what my solution does (please inspect my answer)?

Comment: It could work with stirngs if you store that information in the metadata string, or have another variable that acts as metadata entry for the length of the string (just some int)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `std::variant` or `std::any` (both available in C++17).  If you're using an earlier standard, boost provides `boost::variant` and `boost::any`.

Comment: I also thought about variants, but will it be possible to use it with strings? I need the memory to be somehow allocated at start (parameters need to be global). Could you please inspect my answer? Maybe you see any fundamental misstakes...

Comment: variant will work with std::strings, but if you want the memory allocated at the start of the program you may be out of luck.  An std::string is free to allocate memory when you assign to it, but that's not unique to any solution presented here.  If you just mean making them global, variant shouldn't have any problems with that.